# Is it possible to implement multi-stage SORT using QUERY?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XoxAY8MEgrGrpG1yJ2VthHDOGr6u2pBZC1YotpDfslE/edit?usp=sharing

Tab `Deck Trends` cell `A3` contains the `QUERY` command where you can see the current sorting order.

What I am wanting to achieve is the following:

Any row where `Col E` equals 4, I would like the *secondary* sorting to be based on `Col F`

All other rows I would like the *secondary* sorting to be based on `Col D` (as it currently is set).

Is it even possible to have multiple sorting rules in one `QUERY`?

Comment: is value 4 in E cloumn the highest possible value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({QUERY({
 'Combined Opp Meta'!A2:G11; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A14:G23; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A26:G35},
 "where Col5 = 4
  order by Col5 desc,Col6 desc", 0);
 QUERY({
 'Combined Opp Meta'!A2:G11; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A14:G23; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A26:G35},
 "where Col5 <> 4
  order by Col5 desc,Col4 desc", 0)},
 "limit 12", 0)
```

---

### array literal fix:

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY({
 'Combined Opp Meta'!A2:G11; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A14:G23; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A26:G35},
 "where Col5 = 4
  order by Col5 desc,Col6 desc", 0), {"","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY({
 'Combined Opp Meta'!A2:G11; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A14:G23; 'Combined Opp Meta'!A26:G35},
 "where Col5 <> 4
  order by Col5 desc,Col4 desc", 0), {"","","","","","",""})},
 "where Col1 is not null limit 12", 0)
```

Comment: Absolutely PERFECT!  Thank you so much, this is very helpful, and something I can apply to other aspects of my spreadsheet.  <3

Comment: Oh I just found an issue - when no values in Col5 = 4 it throws an ARRAY_LITERAL error!

Comment: Oh that's much better than what I came up with.  Thanks heaps!